# Another one "undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass" error

Tags: ruby

What's wrong with this code?

I have a .txt file which consist of some attributes like this:

```
attr_one, att2, attr3, attr4
attr_one, att2, attr3, attr4
attr_one, att2, attr3, attr4
```

I want to change "attr1" to "attr_one"

```
require "csv"
people = CSV.read("text.txt")
attr_one = people.find { |person| person[0] =~ /attr_one/ }
attr_one[0] = "attr_one_new"

CSV.open("text.txt", "w") do |csv|
    people.each do |person|
        csv << person
    end
end
```

and how change this to start preceding code work?

```
attr_one[0]...
```

It's example from one reference manual.

Output of this code should be array like that:

```
attr_one, att2, attr3, attr4
attr_one_new, att2, attr3, attr4
attr_one, att2, attr3, attr4
```

Where is mistake?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. We can't see the data--start by breaking down the problem into discrete steps and sanity-check your assumptions by running in the REPL. TL;DR: `name` is `nil`, figure out why.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I would strongly urge you to write to a different file than the one you just read from.  If you've been trying to debug this for a while, you may have destroyed your input file at some point.

Comment: Try `name = people.find { |person| person[0] =~ /Name/ } || []`

Comment: @pjs, it works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `find` returns `nil` because the block never returns a truthy value.

```
attr_one = people.find { |person| person[0] =~ /attr_one/ }
```

This results in the when the following line is called.

```
attr_one[0] = "attr_one_new"
```

Because `nil` doesn't have the `[]=` setter.

The takeaway here is that `find` can return `nil` values.

The [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) says:

> #### find(ifnone = nil) { |obj| block } → obj or nil
>
> #### find(ifnone = nil) → an_enumerator
>
> Passes each entry in *enum* to *block*. Returns the first for which *block*
>   is not false. If no object matches, calls *ifnone* and returns its
>   result when it is specified, or returns `nil` otherwise.
>
> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.
>
> ```
> (1..100).detect  #=> #<Enumerator: 1..100:detect>
> (1..100).find    #=> #<Enumerator: 1..100:find>
>
> (1..10).detect   { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> nil
> (1..10).find     { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> nil
> (1..100).detect  { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> 35
> (1..100).find    { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }   #=> 35
> ```

Comment: so I change this ```attr_one = people.find { |person| person[0] =~ /attr_one/ }``` on this ```attr_one = people.find { |person| person[0] =~ /attr_one/ } || = []``` and this work

Comment: @forMadEline Yes, because `variable = statement_1 || statement_2` assigns the return value of `statement_1` to `variable` if it's truthy or the return value of `statement_2` if `statement_1` was falsy (which `nil`) is.